# Как создать независимые друг от друга экземпляры класса

Tags: c#

В общем, такая ситуация, у меня есть "игра", там есть паук, но он только один и обновление его и прорисовка прописаны в коде изначально, а мне хочется независимо от всего на протяжении игры создавать этих пауков и хочется, чтобы эти пауки обновлялись и рисовались независимо друг от друга.
Я могу сейчас только создать их, на экране ничего не будет (хотя если вывести на экран количество пауков, то количество будет увеличиваться)
У меня была мысль по поводу создания класса с названием "враг" и класса "паук" и потом в классе паука прописать "public Паук : Враг", но я, честно говоря, не до конца понял как это работает.
Так вот, к чему я все это, можно ли сделать так, чтобы я только один раз в самом коде прописал паук.Update() и дальше мог этих пауков пихать куда угодно, чтобы они при этом обновлялись и рисовались?

Да, я "очень хорошо объясняю", но я пока просто не владею нужным словарным запасом, чтобы описать это лучше.
Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: Вам нужно создать экземпляры класса этого паука и делаь с ними, что считаете нужным. Каждый экземпляр будет полностью независим от остальных и жить своей "жизнью". Так же необходимо реализовать методы "жизни" паука,  координаты, нападение и тд. Не знаю, что он у вас там делает, тогда каждый экземпляр будет иметь свое место, перемещаться, нападать и тд.  независимо от остальных

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: @pavlofff а вот и нет, в коде изначально прописан один паук и он живет и все хорошо, а вот если я добавлю еще пауков, но уже в процессе игры, то пауки не появляются и не рисуются

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет никаких проблем делать экземпляры независимыми - как правило, сложность всегда именно с добавлением зависимостей.

Насколько я вас понял, на самом деле ваш вопрос заключается вот в чем:

> Так вот, к чему я все это, можно ли сделать так, чтобы я только один раз в самом коде прописал паук.Update() и дальше мог этих пауков пихать куда угодно, чтобы они при этом обновлялись и рисовались?

Нет, так просто не сделать - именно потому что это сделает всех пауков зависимыми друг от друга. Вам нужно:

1. Завести коллекцию, в которой вы будете этих самых пауков хранить
2. При обновлении пройтись по этой коллекции в цикле, и по-вызывать метод `Update` у всех элементов.

Можно пойти и другим путем. Так, можно создать событие обновления, на которое подписать всех пауков. Это будет похоже на то, что вы предложили изначально - но при повсеместном применении такого подхода могут возникнуть проблемы. Удалить объект из коллекции проще, чем отписать его от разных 10 событий.

Comment: то есть просто сделать лист пауков, потом их туда добавлять и через foreach обновлять?

Comment: Да, вы все поняли правильно.

Comment: Это действительно сработало, спасибо)

Comment: Если сработало, отметьте пожалуйста мой ответ как правильный.